# Use of かて as "even"

Tags: grammar, kansai-ben

> しゃあない。お前かて人間やで。

I get the meaning of the sentence, but I'm wondering, is there a nuance behind かて? For instance, between お前も人間やで。and お前とて and お前でさえ ?

Comment: The quote up there sounds Kansai to me; maybe it's dialectal?

Comment: ＾そうですね、「しょうがない。お前だって人間だよ。」を関西弁で言うとそうなりますね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

かて is Kansai dialect. It is difficult to translate into English, but the usual meaning is similar to "even if...". It is used in place of the standard Japanese particles ~でも、~も or ~さえ、and the verb conjugation ~ても.

Example (like ~ても):

> そんな事ゆうたかて、出来へんもんは出来へんねん。 No matter what you say, what's impossible is
> impossible.
>
> 今からやったかて、無理ちゃう？ Even if you start now, it's already hopeless, isn't
> it?

Example (like  ~さえ):

> そんなん小学生かて知ってるわ。 Even elementary school kids know that.
>
> あたしかていややわ、そんなん。 I don't want to do that, either

Source: Colloquial Kansai Japanese by DC Palter, Kaoru Slotsve

Comment: I often hear ちゃう as well at the end, is that the way they say だろう ? 無理ちゃう

Comment: ちゃう is 違う in Kansai ben and used more frequently than it's standard japanese counterpart. See e.g. this conjugation table: http://www.kansaiben.com/1.Characteristics/2.LinguisticAspects/d-Conjugation.html

Another example of ちゃう: 雨じゃない -> 雨ちゃう